# LU decomposition by parallel MATLAB

Tags: matlab, parallel-processing

I'm trying to compute LU decomposition of NxN matrix in MATLAB with parallel toolbox. I would like to use parfor but there is a problem. Steps in for loop are dependent. This is example of my LU decomposition (columns):

```
function[L, U] = LU_col(A)  

n=size(A,1);
L=eye(n);
U=A    

for k=1:n-1
 L(k+1:n,k) = U(k+1:n,k)/U(k,k);
 for j=k+1:n
   U(k+1:n,j) = U(k+1:n,j) - L(k+1:n,k)*U(k,j);
 end
end

end
```

Do you have any idea how to solve it with parfor? Thanks

Comment: Why not [`lu()`](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/lu.html)?

Comment: I'd recommend using the intrinsic `lu` which is, I believe, multi-threaded and will execute in parallel on a multicore machine.

Answer (score 0):

The contract for `parfor` includes the following somewhat vague comment "Restrictions apply to the STATEMENTS in the loop body".  These restrictions include anything which prevents this from being [embarrassingly parallel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Embarrassingly_parallel).  In your case, each element of L and U will be modified by multiple loops, which means that the iterations of the for loop would need some coordination, which triggers Matlab's safety checks on use of the `parfor` commands.

I would be very surprised if you could find a workaround for this, without implementing a major change to the algorithm.

To echo prior comments, the built-in `lu` command should be very efficient.  As a built-in, it's implementation is most likely compiled C or Fortan with heavy use of best in class linear algebra libraries.

Answer (score 0):

As High Performance Mark points out, MATLAB's built-in LU is multithreaded and therefore pretty much guaranteed to beat the performance of anything you might try in PARFOR on a single machine. If you have several machines, your best bet is to use a [distributed](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/distcomp/distributed.html) array.

```
matlabpool open mycluster 64
d = distributed.rand(60000);
[l, u] = lu(d);
```